# How to search for a name in two columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to search a name 'Hamed Haddadi'. 'Hamed' is first name and 'Haddadi' is the last name of the user. When I search individually in the first name and last name columns it shows a record.

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbaplayermaster 
WHERE firstname LIKE "%Hamed%" OR 
      lastname LIKE "%Haddadi%";
```

But whenever I search his name in two columns, it shows an empty result set in MySQL.

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbaplayermaster 
WHERE firstname LIKE "%Hamed Haddadi%" OR 
      lastname LIKE "%Hamed Haddadi%";
```

I want to search his full name in two columns.

Comment: Please present data from your table

Comment: You can use sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) for this and share the link afterwards. As you've stated that the firstname is "Hamed" and "Haddadi" his last name, I do not understand why you expect to find someone whose first name is "Hamed Haddadi" or his last name is "Hamed Haddadi". @moderators: should this question be migrated to stackoverflow?

Comment: @ShlomiNoach data of nbaplayermaster. Please click this link http://imgur.com/lVN3WLm

Comment: Please do not ask very basic SQL questions here.  I realize you can't ask questions on SO, that doesn't mean it's OK to ask questions that are off-topic on our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbaplayermaster
WHERE   "Hamed Haddadi" LIKE Concat(Concat('%',firstname),'%') 
OR "Hamed Haddadi" LIKE  Concat(Concat('%',lastname),'%')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f13a1/7)

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that Hamed is the first name and Haddadi is the last name, you can do it in 3 ways;

**Solution 1:**

Split the query in name and last name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbaplayermaster 
WHERE firstname LIKE "%Hamed%" OR 
      lastname LIKE "%Hamed%";
```

**Solution 2:**

Use the wildcard % in between the names(spaces)

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbaplayermaster 
WHERE firstname LIKE "%Hamed%Haddadi%" OR 
      lastname LIKE "%Hamed%Haddadi%";
```

**Solution 3:(recommended)**

Add a fulltext index on this 2 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE nbaplayermaster ADD FULLTEXT KEY `full_name` (`firstname`,`lastname`);
```

and then search using the fulltext index

```
SELECT * FROM nbaplayermaster WHERE MATCH(firstname,lastname) AGAINST ('Hamed Haddadi');
```

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me